# Reclassification table keeps giving Error in table(c1, c2, data[, cOutcome]) : all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r, package

```
reclassification(data=Data, cOutcome=cOutcome, predrisk1=predRisk1, predrisk2=predRisk2, cutoff)
```

_________________________________________

```
 Reclassification table
```

Error in table(c1, c2, data[, cOutcome]) :
all arguments must have the same length`

---

```
library(PredictABEL)
### 1.1  versus 1.1 +CAC model

logistic.model.list <- 
  list(Basic_m = glm(Data$Event11 ~ gender + Age_at_scan + RF_currentsmoking  + RF_DM_combi + PTP_cat, data = Data, family = binomial), 
       New_m   = glm(Data$Event11 ~ gender + Age_at_scan + RF_currentsmoking  + RF_DM_combi + PTP_cat + CAC_cat, 
                 data = Data, family = binomial) )

reclassification(data = Data, cOutcome = 4, 
                 predrisk1 = fitted(logistic.model.list[["Basic_m"]]), 
                 predrisk2 = fitted(logistic.model.list[["New_m"]]), 
                 cutoff = c(0, 0.05, 0.15, 1)
```

```
dput(my_data)
```

`structure(list(key = c(163, 315, 524, 553, 667, 724, 786, 1017,  1420, 1431, 1476, 1496, 1547, 1556, 1580, 1592, 1667, 1754, 1849,  2013, 2020, 2067, 2337, 2401, 2549, 2550, 2650, 2659, 2770, 2775,  2836, 2851, 3034, 3099, 3102, 3152, 3268, 3517, 3656, 3807, 3854,  4143, 4215, 4224, 4311, 4363, 4384, 4483, 4597, 4649), Event11 = c(0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Event12 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),  time_event_11 = c(10.0056468172485, 3.1170431211499, 5.91786447638604,  2.12183436002738, 11.7794984409461, 1.06639288158795, 12.318769488174,  7.8014525819454, 11.2014677922275, 9.01704502243517, 7.28678986995209,  1.22381930184805, 10.6984941820671, 11.5482546201232, 10.2110997033996,  8.07118412046543, 7.45106091718001, 8.04011521788735, 8.68040915658985,  5.33196440793977, 2.39014373716632, 10.9803216974675, 9.50444900752909,  10.6848619666894, 11.4203874819377, 10.868210510305, 8.39536656779983,  3.15537303216975, 6.34360027378508, 6.22724161533196, 4.02076203513569,  7.77960301163587, 8.68306525211037, 7.41683778234086, 2.45037645448323,  9.48208989276745, 11.937029431896, 2.68789451669322, 0.0602327173169062,  7.38827857631765, 10.7583941744619, 6.17014601870859, 7.0403832991102,  10.555226633204, 7.63997262149213, 8.93474788957341, 11.709787816564,  10.848733744011, 8.34933264887064, 9.66636246102359), time_event_12 = c(10.0056468172485,  3.1170431211499, 5.91786447638604, 2.12183436002738, 11.7794984409461,  1.06639288158795, 12.318769488174, 7.8014525819454, 11.2014677922275,  9.01704502243517, 7.19104114381328, 1.22381930184805, 10.6984941820671,  11.5482546201232, 10.2110997033996, 8.07118412046543, 7.45106091718001,  8.04011521788735, 8.68040915658985, 5.33196440793977, 2.39014373716632,  10.9803216974675, 9.50444900752909, 2.63381245722108, 11.4203874819377,  10.868210510305, 8.39536656779983, 3.15537303216975, 6.34360027378508,  6.22724161533196, 4.02076203513569, 7.77960301163587, 8.68306525211037,  7.41683778234086, 2.45037645448323, 9.48208989276745, 11.937029431896,  2.68789451669322, 0.0602327173169062, 7.38827857631765, 10.7583941744619,  6.17014601870859, 7.0403832991102, 10.555226633204, 7.63997262149213,  8.93474788957341, 11.709787816564, 10.848733744011, 8.34933264887064,  9.66636246102359), Age_at_scan = c(36.9185489390828, 60.9077116130504,  85.0199263568839, 70.9418206707734, 69.0443759981748, 73.9480568864553,  62.0630846452202, 80.0781056861105, 66.2409308692676, 59.158224960073,  60.6913073237509, 65.4525439196897, 45.8741729409081, 46.4271047227926,  77.8631843993206, 60.6365503080082, 67.0294318959617, 54.84610997034,  63.5168834131873, 61.8466803559206, 61.1157882728725, 47.8124572210815,  58.1972393337896, 74.2273185540092, 76.9761207442898, 55.2951174994296,  42.1342687656856, 72.570841889117, 53.7659137577002, 79.9822809085609,  80.026086521155, 68.732489162674, 59.738649326945, 40.8036732831394,  72.7132870687251, 63.3771389459274, 57.5675336527493, 54.5668491900525,  74.2081527112329, 47.9576773899156, 58.684462696783, 58.1067761806982,  82.6216831444723, 59.4537987679671, 73.5921371713945, 63.2867898699521,  65.2169746748802, 59.2650011407712, 53.7591832078485, 59.9823180469998 ), gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("men",  "women"), class = "factor"), BMI = c(23.0577256944444, 22.4058769513315,  23.9868703446535, 37.7777777777778, 24.1588179685585, 28.0557057869118,  23.9389897746315, 25.4028160836116, 29.8027757487217, 23.9590942293645,  22.038567493113, 27.4725274725275, 26.8809349890431, 27.4238227146814,  28.515625, 25.8477682188187, 29.0547520661157, 36.9321237763993,  27.6360544217687, 41.6666666666667, 36.4197530864198, 33.802055164954,  22.2569083130998, 24.8015873015873, 34.1985568209022, 26.2975778546713,  22.8373702422145, 21.7180660897457, 31.25, 23.4375, 22.0931700542861,  24.8356464572681, 32.6530612244898, 22.3402970655718, 22.038567493113,  35.8782454380618, 27.1707711874205, 27.1731016154558, 26.0043827611395,  38.5343428880476, 30.1102788964583, 21.5450907971684, 23.0545624644993,  25.5102040816327, 25.2493372048984, 22.0931700542861, 28.0403781445281,  24.7842575173938, 26.7755102040816, 22.5308641975309), RF_currentsmoking = structure(c(2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"),  RF_DM_combi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("No",  "Yes"), class = "factor"), RF_hypercholesterolmia_combi = structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"),  RF_hypertension_combi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("No",  "Yes"), class = "factor"), RF_first_degree_CAD_combi = structure(c(2L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"),  Med_aspirin_combi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("No",  "Yes"), class = "factor"), Med_beta_combi = structure(c(1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"),  Med_stat_combi = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("No",  "Yes"), class = "factor"), Med_ACE_combi = structure(c(1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"),  new_RMcategories = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Normal scan",  "Irreversible", "Ischemia"), class = "factor"), New_combi = structure(c(4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("Normal scan", "moderate defect",  "Moderate ischemia", "small defect", "Small ischemia"), class = "factor"),  Isch_size = c("Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal",  "Normal", "Normal", "Normal"), Complaints_2019 = structure(c(3L,  1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L,  1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L,  4L, 1L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("aspecific chestpain", "typical AP",  "atypical AP", "Dyspnea"), class = "factor"), PTP_cat = structure(c(1L,  2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,  3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("5", "515", "15"), class = "factor"),  CAC_cat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L,  3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L,  3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), levels = c("0",  "1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Type_event12 = structure(c(NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = c("ACS",  "late revasc", "CD", "no event"), class = "factor"), Type_event11 = structure(c(3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("ACS", "cardiac death", "no event" ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))`

\Im trying to calculate the NRI categorical from my data. My outcome is Event11 (0 is no event, 1 is event).  I used predictors which i categorised and one continous variable. There is no missing data.
Events are column 4 in my dataset. I f look at predrisk1 and 2 both the vectors are just as long as Event11.  This is the code i used.

Can somebody give a hint what i did wrong?\

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It will be easier to help if you can make your question reproducible, such as by including some sample data we can run. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example